# GOLF CPU - Implement Arbitrary Precision Integer Division

Tags: math, number, golf-cpu, fewest-operations

*This question was inspired [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55798/implement-arbitrary-precision-integer-division) and @orlp's comment and a lot of the explanation was copied from there.*

Write a [*GOLF*](https://github.com/orlp/golf-cpu) assembly program that given two arbitrary size decimal integers `a`, and `b` from stdin outputs two decimal integers to stdout, `Q` and `R`  such that `b * Q + R = a`. In other words write divmod with arbitrary precision integers.

### Clarifications

- `abs(R)` must be less than `abs(b)`
- You do not need to deal with `b = 0`
- `a` and `b` are decimal string representing integers in `(-inf, inf)`, space separated.
- Output is also space separated in order `Q R`.
- Your score is the sum of `# of cycles * (513 - test case size)` for each test-case where the size is listed next to each test-case.
- This is a [fewest-operations](/questions/tagged/fewest-operations) challenge so lowest score wins!
- **Your GOLF binary (after assembling) must fit in 4096 bytes.**

### Test Cases

```
(8 bit) 236 7 -> 33 5
(32 bit) 2262058702 39731 -> 56934 13948
(128 bit) 189707885178966019419378653875602882632 15832119745771654346 -> 11982469070803487349 12121955145791013878
(512 bit) 6848768796889169874108860690670901859917183532000531459773526799605706568321891381716802882255375829882573819813967571454358738985835234480369798040222267 75399690492001753368449636746168689222978555913165373855679892539145717693223 -> 90832850270329337927688719359412349209720255337814924816375492347922352354493 57944926054000242856787627886619378599467822371491887441227330826275320521328
```

---

You should read [the  *GOLF* specification with all instructions and cycle costs](https://github.com/orlp/golf-cpu/blob/master/specification.md). In the Github repository example programs can be found.

Comment: Can we choose which way to round negative numbers?

Comment: Can we get examples with one or more negative inputs?

Comment: Temporarily putting this on hold until the rules for negative inputs are clarified.